# How to add logo or watermark overlay on movie with `mkvmerge` in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 14.04

I add *.srt* files to the video with this command:

```
mkvmerge -o /root/vod/moviewithsrt.mkv /root/vod/moviewithout srt.mp4 /root/vod/Subtitle.srt
```

How to add png logo or watermark overlay on movie with `mkvmerge` in Ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg` to add an overlay.
This command will add logo.png to the center of the video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" \
-codec:a copy output.mp4
```

For more information and credits goes to: [How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918907/how-to-add-transparent-watermark-in-center-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: OK thx allot,can you please tell me how add png in top right or left corner.

Comment: @ValentinoZec, check the link, it has a lot of alignments available, if anything wrong occurs, feel free to comment...